# Get HTML div id in python [Flask web application]

Tags: python, html, flask

So I am making a web app using Flask. And I want the `app.py` file to get the `id` of an html div from the `index.html` file

```
<td><a href="/edit" id="{{ i+1 }}">Edit</a>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<a href="/delete">&#10006;</a></td>
```

the `{{ i+1 }}` is in jiinja format. I want that to be sent to `app.py` when `Edit` is clicked

Comment: maybe `href="/edit?{{i+1}}"`

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on how would this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> maybe `href="/edit?{{i+1}}"` - [Ouroborus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/367865/ouroborus)

Good idea.

```
<td>
    <a href="/edit/?id={{i+1}}">Edit</a>
    &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
    <a href="/delete">&#10006;</a>
</td>
```

and the backend:

```
@app.route('/edit/')
def edit():
    Id = request.args.get("id")
    # ...
```

Comment: One small problem. the code `Id = request.args.get("id")` only works in the `GET` method of `edit()` and not in the `POST` method. Any idea what can be done?

Comment: @UpanshuLakhani Maybe put a hidden field in the page or add it to the action attribute of your form action="/edit/?id={{i+1}}"